# Main circuit breaker keeps tripping

Tags: maintenance

my main circuit breaker keeps tripping randomly. I have hired an electrical servicing company, they have rewired the Water heater system and installed separate circuit breaker (thinking it could have been the cause) but no change. Now they want to install Ac Isolators with RCD protection (what ever that is).

Is it possible for so-called certified electricians not to figure out the exact cause of this tripping? please advise me

Comment: Please post a picture of the exact device tripping. Whether it's an RCD, AFDD, a breaker, or just a switch, they can trip on different things.

Answer (score 2):

I had this many years ago.

My Dad and I went round the house and unplugged / disconnected **every** single device - clocks, tv, washing machine etc etc etc really every single one in every room.

Switched the breaker back on and it was fine.

So, room by room went round and re-connected each device...
All was well **until** we re-connected the washing machine - it had developed a fault and as it was 25 years old it was replaced.

So, try a logical measured approach - the solution may be simpler than you expect - worth trying as it is cheaper than letting those electricians fit anything they can think of...

Comment: Mike thank you for this piece of advice am gonna try it out.

Comment: The only reason the electrician won't recommend this because it's a very time-consuming process, and you couldn't afford to pay him to be there for all of it.   As such, this sort of troubleshooting/mapping job *very much lends itself to DIY*.

Comment: @Harper are you possibly suggesting electricians just sell you stuf you don’t really need due to time restraints?

Comment: @SolarMike they would offer that kind of trouble shooting but the amount of time spent on it means a higher bill that the customer won't pay and find the other guy that will just replace the breaker.

Comment: What I mean is the only reason she won't recommend paying her to do it, is you are perfectly capable of doing it yourself for free!

Comment: @Harper I was and did.... AND at 15 years old as well...